# Python - Delete all files EXCEPT for

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python script and I'm trying to delete all files in this directory EXCEPT for the .csv file.  Getting syntax error on the "not" in this line:

```
for CleanUp not in glob.glob("c:\python\AIO*.*"):
```

If I remove the "not", it will delete the AIO.csv file, but I need to preserve that file and ONLY that file.  Not clear why it's not working.

```
import os
import glob
import time

file_path = "c:\python\AIO.csv"
while not os.path.exists(file_path):
    time.sleep(10)

if os.path.isfile(file_path):
 #Verifies CSV file was created, then deletes unneeded files.
    for CleanUp not in glob.glob("c:\python\AIO*.*"):
        os.remove(CleanUp)
```

Comment: You can't have a not in a for loop. You can in an if statement however

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: It's probably good this doesn't work ... because if it did, it would remove every file that didn't match your glob, including stuff in c:\windows etc.

Comment: The [**watchdog**](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog) library might help you with monitoring a directory to see when a file appears

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this instead

```
import os
import glob
import time

file_path = "c:\python\AIO.csv"
while not os.path.exists(file_path):
    time.sleep(10)

if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    # Verifies CSV file was created, then deletes unneeded files.
    for clean_up in glob.glob('C:/python/*.*'):
        print(clean_up)
        if not clean_up.endswith('AIO.csv'):    
            os.remove(clean_up)
```

`glob` doesn't print any directories, only files, and it also gets the entire path so you can just call `os.remove(clean_up)`. This should work. It works on my machine which is also Windows 7 x64.

I think your problem was that you were looping over the path `c:\python\AIO*.*` which is a file so it only does one loop and terminates which skips all other files in the directory

Comment: It would be safer to compare with `file_path` instead of checking just the ending (extension), because a file named let's say `abc.csv` would be skipped.

Comment: SirParselot - doesn't seem to be working.  It doesn't error, but it also doesn't do anything.  I'm using Python 2.7.2 in case it matters.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I may have misunderstood the question but you are saying that file_path should be the only file left right?

Comment: @user3108489 in that you only want file_path left?

Comment: Yes, only the .csv file should remain.

Comment: @user3108489 I updated my answer and it should work the way it is now. If it isn't working then double check that is even finding the file.

Comment: SirParselot - you are right.  When I changed the "AIO*.*" to just *.* it worked.  Thank you.

Comment: @SirParselot, why not `if CleanUp != file_path: os.remove(CleanUp)`?

Comment: This forum changed my last response.  "When I changed the "AIO*.*" to just "*.*" it worked. Thank you"

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu - this looks like an elegant solution as well.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu no particular reason. Either way should work

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way would be get the list of files (glob.glob returns a list) and then remove the one item you want to preserve.

```
import os
import glob
import time

file_path = "c:\python\AIO.csv"
while not os.path.exists(file_path):
    time.sleep(10)

if os.path.isfile(file_path):
   # get list of files that match
   cleanupFiles = glob.glob("c:\python\AIO*.*")
   cleanupFiles.remove(file_path)
   for cleanupFile in cleanupFiles:
      os.remove(cleanupFile)
```

Comment: This method behaved the same way.  Didn't do anything.  The script acts like it finished, but is just sitting in memory (python.exe *32).  Must be something weird going on on my end.